# Can't read file properly from windows notepad

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I write some codes for simple text editor in C# and I use rich text box control, I found a problem that I can't solve. The problem is when I save a file in my text editor and then try to reopen it using windows notepad, it become in one line, this is the example

This is when I write and save from my app

[image]

After I save it and open in windows notepad it becomes like this
[image]

here are my code for saving a fie

```
try
{
    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    this.Text = file = toolStripTextBox1.Text = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
    isi = richTextBox1.Text;
    write = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file);
    write.WriteLine(isi);
    write.Close();
    toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "Saved";
}
catch (Exception)
{
    toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "Save cancelled by user";
}
```

do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably getting this because you are trying to save `richTextBox1.Text` (the whole text) in one line only using the following code

```
isi = richTextBox1.Text;
write = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file);
write.WriteLine(isi);
write.Close();
```

It's recommended to use `write.WriteLine()` on a specific line number in `richTextBox1` then move to another line.

**Example**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
 {
      write.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Lines[i]);
 }
write.Close();
```

### **Another Solution**

---

There's already a built-in function for `RichTextBox` to save a file with a specific encoding. You may use `RichTextBox.SaveFile()` for this purpose.

**Example**

```
RichTextBox.SaveFile(string path, RichTextBoxStreamType);
```

Where path represents `saveFileDialog1.FileName` in your code. For `RichTextBoxStreamType`, it's best to set it as `RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText` as long as you do not use RTF such as Color/Font/Protection/Indent/etc...

Then, you may read the file again using the following method

```
RichTextBox.LoadFile(string path, RichTextBoxStreamType);
```

**NOTICE:** If the file is not in RTF and you try to read it in RTF (`RichTextBox.LoadFile(string path, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);`)
 you may encounter formatting errors. In this case, you'll need to catch the exception and read the file in a Plain or Unicode encoding.

**Example**

```
RichTextBox _RichTextBox = new RichTextBox();
try
{
     _RichTextBox.LoadFile(@"D:\Resources\text.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
}
catch (Exception EX)
{
     if (EX.Message.ToLower().Contains("format is not valid"))
     {
          _RichTextBox.LoadFile(@"D:\Resources\text.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
     }
}
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Saves the contents of the RichTextBox to a file by using richtextbox 's own save method: `SaveFile(string, RichTextBoxStreamType);`
you can refer this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.savefile%28VS.71%29.aspx

load the content of file by `LoadFile(Stream, RichTextBoxStreamType);`, refer this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.loadfile(v=vs.71).aspx